# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

in an usercontrol with update panel when using the scriptManger to register a script this code is works:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
        (this.updatePanel, this.updatePanel.GetType(), "printing", Keys.URL, true);
```

but this one does not work

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "printing", Keys.URL, true);
```

i cant figure why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would think it's because in the first example you're registering a script for the `UpdatePanel` (which would be updated on an asynchronous postback - enabling the script to be written), whereas in the second example you're doing it at the `page` level, which wouldn't be updated as it falls outside the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Yes very right since update panel is used for partial post back so the script is not loaded for the page in the second time because of partial postback